# Selecting Dropdown item, triggering click event, clicking on button and extract output from website

Tags: javascript, vba, dom, web-scraping

[Find Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khNZA.jpg)Process:
UPDATE:
When I manually select a Combobox option on the website, an event is triggered which updates the 'Lot Size' below (Please see the Screenshot). But when using VBA to copy symbol to the Combobox, the said event is not triggered. I've tried using FireEvent, dispatchEvent, etc., but all in vain. Any help would be much appreciated.

- I need to go to this URL "https://zerodha.com/margin-calculator/SPAN/",
- Select NFO as Exchange, Options as Product
- Copy symbol from Range("A1") to Symbol
- Enter strike price from Range("A2")
- Select Sell radio button
- Click on "Add" button.

After the page gets loaded, I need to copy the total margin from the webpage to Range("A3").

I have managed to write the following code, but I seem to have gotten stuck and I'd appreciate some help.

```
Sub setOpt()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://zerodha.com/margin-calculator/SPAN/"

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
    
    Set HTML = IE.document

    Dim drp As HTMLFormElement
    
    Set drp = HTML.getElementById("exchange[]")
    drp.selectedIndex = 0

    Set drp = HTML.getElementById("product[]")
    drp.selectedIndex = 1                        'working fine until here
    drp.FireEvent ("OnChange")                   'And I become clueless here

    Dim event_onChange As Object
    
    Set event_onChange = HTML.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    event_onChange.initEvent "change", True, False

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim field As HTMLInputElement
    
    Set field = HTML.getElementById("select2-scrip-container")
    field.Value = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please describe this getting stuck. Error messages? If so, what and were? What is happening instead of what should?

Comment: You have entered the wrong ids. You have used name instead of id e.g. product id is `product` not `product[]`

Comment: @QHarr - The IDs are just fine and the code seems to be working till the FireEvent method. I'm currently stuck at trying to trigger the event after copying Symbol into a combobox on the website (Please see the attached screenshot). Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, No, I still think your ids are wrong e.g. `<select class="in changer" name="exchange[]" id="exchange" wfd-id="94">..........</select>`

Comment: @QHarr - Thank you for the reply. I've made the changes you pointed out, but the FireEvent method still eludes me. The value that I have in Cell A1 is copied into the Combo Box, but the website still shows the value for the default Combo Box Symbol, when "Add" button is clicked. Therefore, I still need to trigger an event when the Combo Box value is entered. SendKeys "~" too doesn't work, but Enter key works on the website when I enter the value manually.